# Is IdentityServer4 .Net standard or .Net core?

Tags: identityserver4, nuget-package

I'm working on a project using [IdentityServer 4](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/).

While working on some documentation, I realized that IdentityServer 4 is described as a "framework for ASP.NET Core."

However, after checking the NuGet packages I'm using, I've seen that they are provided as .Net Standard. And this since the very first version. And speaking of the very first version, it was even .Net Framework dependent.

So I was wondering why is IdentityServer 4 a framework for ASP.NET Core if it's packages are built in .Net Standard.

Sorry if the question is considered too broad. I'm just trying to understand how all of this packaging stuff works.

Answer (score 0):

It may target .Net Standard but it directly depends on Microsoft.AspNetCode.* packages and is implemented as ASP.Net Core middleware so it's an accurate statement.